# Query returning data about nested elements

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I have three tables in my database:

```
boards: idBoard, nameBoard, author
sections: idSection, nameSection, idBoard
tasks: idTask, nameTask, idSection
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT tasks.idTask, sections.idSection, (more...) 
FROM `tasks` 
    INNER JOIN `boards` ON tasks.idBoard = boards.idBoard 
    INNER JOIN `sections` ON sections.idSection = tasks.idSection 
WHERE boards.idBoard = ? 
AND boards.author= ?
```

The query works almost well, but it doesn't return `sections` that don't have their `tasks` items.
Unfortunately, I don't really know why it works like that. I would also like to get `section` items matching `boards` but not having `tasks` items

Comment: Do you know how `INNER JOIN` works? Do you know the other types of join - other than `INNER JOIN`? (Hint: `LEFT JOIN`)

Comment: Your query references `tasks.idBoard` which is not in the tables you describe.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: You probably need `INDEX(author, idBoard)` (in either order).

Answer (score 0):

I think you made a mistake in your query. tasks table doesn't have a column called 'idBoard' in your post.

How about this?

```
SELECT tasks.idTask, sections.idSection, (more...) 
FROM `tasks` 
INNER JOIN `sections` ON sections.idSection = tasks.idSection     
INNER JOIN `boards` ON sections.idBoard = boards.idBoard   

WHERE boards.idBoard = ? 
AND boards.author= ?
```

Could you explain more about what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want outer joins, which usually means `left join`.  Based on the way you describe your tables, I would expect the query to look like this:

```
SELECT t.idTask, s.idSection, (more...) 
FROM boards b LEFT JOIN
     sections s
     ON b.idBoard = s.idBoard 
     tasks t
     ON s.idSection = t.idSection 
WHERE b.idBoard = ?  AND boards.author= ?
```